# Swipe to refresh to update data

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a recyclerview that I want to update when a user swipes to refresh.

this is my MainActity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Coin>> {

private val mCoinLoaderId = 1
private val mCoinEndpointUrl = "http://coincap.io/front"
private var swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    swipeRefreshLayout=  findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout) as SwipeRefreshLayout

    rv_coins.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rv_coins.setHasFixedSize(true)
    runLoaders()


    swipeRefreshLayout?.setOnRefreshListener{


                // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
                // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
                runLoaders()
            }



}

private fun runLoaders() {

    val connManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val networkInfo = connManager.activeNetworkInfo
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected) {
        loaderManager.initLoader(mCoinLoaderId, null , this)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}


override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<List<Coin>> {
    val baseUri: Uri = Uri.parse(mCoinEndpointUrl)


    return object : AsyncTaskLoader<List<Coin>>(this) {
        override fun onStartLoading() {
            forceLoad()
        }

        override fun loadInBackground(): List<Coin>? {
            return QueryUtils.fetchCoinData(baseUri.toString())
        }
    }
}

override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<List<Coin>>?, data: List<Coin>?) {
    if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {

        progressBar1.isEnabled = false
        if(swipeRefreshLayout?.isRefreshing!!)  {
            swipeRefreshLayout?.isRefreshing = false
        }

        rv_coins.adapter = CoinAdapter(data)
    }



}

override fun onLoaderReset(loader: Loader<List<Coin>>?) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```

and I have the following adapter

```
class CoinAdapter(private val mCoinData: List<Coin>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CoinAdapter.CoinViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): CoinViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
    return CoinViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CoinViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    holder?.mCoinShortNameTV?.text = mCoinData[position].short
    holder?.mCoinLongNameTV?.text = mCoinData[position].longname
    holder?.mCoinPercentageTV?.text = """${mCoinData[position].perc.toString()}%"""
    if (mCoinData[position].perc < 0.0) {
        holder?.mCoinPercentageTV?.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F73757"))
    } else {
        holder?.mCoinPercentageTV?.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#21BD2E"))
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mCoinData.size
}


inner class CoinViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val mCoinLongNameTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.long_name) as TextView
    val mCoinPercentageTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.percentage) as TextView
    val mCoinShortNameTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.short_name) as TextView
}
```

But even though I called runLoaders() function while the user is swiping to refresh, it is not updating the data. It is not even calling the fetch function to update the data.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: you call initLoader, it will run once, try to change it to restartLoader, so it will run every time when called

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
loaderManager.initLoader(mCoinLoaderId, null, this).forceLoad()
```

instead of

```
loaderManager.initLoader(mCoinLoaderId, null, this)
```